# Разница между UTF-8 и UTF-16

Tags: xml, sql-server, xsd

В чем принципиальная разница между UTF-8 и UTF-16?

Просто есть две схемы XML, в которых 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` и `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`.

Проблема в том, что в MS SQL оператор не срабатывает с utf-8.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

utf-8 - это кодировка с переменным числом байт на символ, в то время как в utf-16 все символы занимают 2 байта.

Comment: Я, возможно, не так понял, но у utf-8 блок из 8 бит и для кодирования используется от 1 до 4 блоков, у utf-16 блок 16 бит и для кодирования используется один или 2 блока. Что-нибудь произойдет, если я вручную изменю в xml utf-8 на utf-16? Или необходимо каким-то образом переконвертировать их?

Comment: utf 8 от 1 до, кажется, шести, utf 16 строго два байта. Нужно перекодировать.

Comment: у utf-16 могут быть суррогатные пары, тогда на один символ идет 4 байта.

а вот перекодировать - это точно нужно.

Comment: А еще utf-8 позволяет кодировать числа размером 31 бит (max 0x7FFFFFFF), а utf-16 только 20 (0xFFFFF).

Comment: Это неверно, в UTF-16 один code point может кодироваться в 4 байта. UTF-16 тоже variable-length encoding.

Comment: Вы наверное utf-16 с ucs-2 спутали, где действительно на символ 2 байта.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian "Both UTF-8 and UTF-32 are clearly superior to the vicious hack previously known as Mrs UTF-16, whose maiden name was UCS-2"