# Как определить нерусский текст?

Tags: java, unicode, кириллица

Допустим, имеется строка. Как определить, что она содержит нерусские символы? Потенциальный текст не содержит специальных символов, кроме пробелов.
Конечно, можно было бы проверить наличие того или иного символа, но я думаю, что есть более простой и эффективный способ.

Посоветуйте, как это осуществить максимально быстро?

Comment: Пробел, запятая, точка, тире, скобки, кавычки считаются нерусскими? А китайские кавычки (『 』)? А немецкие (»вот такие«)?

Comment: "12345" - это русский текст или нет? ;-)

Comment: конечно можно было бы проверить наличие того или иного символа, но я думаю что есть более простой и эффективный способ

Comment: еще прикол в том что потенциальный текст не содержит специальных символов, разве что только пробелы.

Comment: @Eugen: Вы всё же ответьте на вопрос, без этого невозможно вам ничего посоветовать. Давайте ещё докину: а белорусская ў? А исконно русский ять ѣ?

Comment: @VladD: считаются

Comment: *но я думаю что есть более простой и эффективный способ* - что вас навело на эту мысль?

Comment: [Готовые регулярные выражения, описывающие алфавиты большинства распространенных языков](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/181472)

Comment: Извините, на Java не пишу, так что ответ предлагать не стану. Но ведь Java кодирует в UTF-16, да? Создайте битовую карту по всем 65 536 значениям UTF-16, и по ней в цикле смотрите.

Не понимаю, с какой стати вопрос минуснули. Автор чётко сказал: нерусские *символы* (т.е. те, которых в русском тексте нет), а не нерусский *текст.*

Comment: @IncnisMrsi 65535 значений UTF-16? Что вы имеете в виду под "значениями" и почему только 2^16?

Comment: @VladD ещё хитрый случай придумал. Если к кириллической Е добавить комбинированное двоеточие, символ считается русским?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Хороший вопрос. По идее, у них должна быть одинаковая [каноническая композиция](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms). Но об этом должна заботиться механика регулярных выражений, наверное, а не программист. (Но между «должна заботиться» и «в реальности свалено на программиста» есть хорошая пропасть, конечно.)

Comment: @VladD ага, я за три недели изучения юникода набрался пессимизма на этот счёт).

Comment: @VladD я даже не поручусь, что все возможные варианты пробелов там описаны)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Тогда буду следить за вашими ответами, позапоминаю, где там подводные камни :)

Comment: @VladD кстати, в ответах тоже изрядно заблуждений. С C# так же? (Пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/407454/181472)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Да, в самом начале было практически стандартом игнорировать символы вне BMP, так что UTF-16 считалась кодировкой с фиксированным числом байт на символ. Вот [статья Эрика](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/04/09/why-utf-16/#.WHPtxWq7ouU) по этому поводу. Хуже того, в C# строковые функции (например, `Length`) работают в 16-битных словах, а не в code point'ах, так что проблема есть и будет ещё долго. :-(

Comment: @VladD остается только грустно вздыхать и пиарить utf8everywhere.org)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Я не вижу особых причин использования utf-8, а не utf-16. У них примерно одинаковый круг проблем, разве что utf-16 бывает little и big endian. Разве есть ещё какие-то преимущества?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "[" +                   //начало списка допустимых символов
                    "а-яА-ЯёЁ" +    //буквы русского алфавита
                    "\\d" +         //цифры
                    "\\s" +         //знаки-разделители (пробел, табуляция и т.д.)
                    "\\p{Punct}" +  //знаки пунктуации
            "]" +                   //конец списка допустимых символов
            "*");                   //допускается наличие указанных символов в любом количестве
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Посоветуйте, как это осуществить максимально быстро?");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());//true

    matcher = pattern.matcher("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());//false
}
```

Если требуется разрешить еще какие-то символы, следует добавить их между квадратными скобками `[]`. См. также JavaDoc к классу [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Для других языков можно использовать тот же самый код, заменив `"а-яА-ЯёЁ"` на [готовые регулярные выражения, описывающие алфавиты большинства распространенных языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/181472)

Comment: Кстати, не факт, что регулярка — это максимально быстро.

Comment: "допускается наличие указанных символов **в любом количестве**" но хотя бы один-то там должен быть? Может, все же "+", а не "*" ?

Comment: _Может, все же "+"_ - комментарий к выражению соответствует действию, им выполняемому (* это 0 или более раз, т.е. **в любом количестве**). Поставленная задача, если коротко: проверить есть в тексте _не русские символы_ или нет. Смена * на + будет решать уже другую задачу - проверить, чтобы в тексте был 1 или более символ русского языка.

Answer (score 3):

Если *быстро* и строка длинная (что считать длинным это отдельный вопрос), то можно проверить несколько (скажем, 0.1 от длины строки) случайных символов на попадание в диапазон от 'А' до 'я' и если их процент выше заданного, то считать строку русским текстом.
(наверное, для коротких строк быстрее проверять все символы).

Comment: Делать классифицирующий алгоритм случайно-зависимым? Не думаю, что это хорошая мысль. «Разрешить или нет… ?» Сейчас, кости только подброшу ☺

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, скажите это разработчикам [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html): `ANALYZE TABLE determines index cardinality... by doing random dives to each of the index trees and updating index cardinality estimates accordingly` А ведь кардинальность индекса играет не маленькую роль в оптимизаторе

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко: явным образом перечислить все искомые символы плюс знаки препинания в регулярном выражении и проверять им строку.

Осталось [определить множество русских символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/181472).

Comment: Перечислить что, **не** русские? В Unicode, ага?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: конечно нет, перечислить русские  и проверять, что каждый символ входит в множество. Прочитайте принятый ответ.

Comment: Смысл? Не разбираюсь в Жаве, чтобы судить о скорости регулярки в сравнении с циклами.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: в принятом ответе реализуется то, что я описал словами в этом. Раз он вызвал у вас сомнения, можете посмотреть на реализацию. Регулярка там видна и без знания Java.

Comment: Знаю, что Вас раздражаю, но семантика слова **искомый** не соответствует тому, о чём Вы думаете.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: в данном случае искомыми символами являются именно символы русского алфавита. Мы ищем их в каждом символе, и если хоть в одном не находим, то текст — «не русский». Искать символы множества  `Unicode \ {символы русского алфавита }` не представляется возможным.

Comment: А, в Вашем мире поиск происходит *в словаре,* а не в строке. Понятия обращены относительно моих. Да, теперь понял, хотя не стал бы думать как о поиске об том, что может быть реализовано путём обращения по адресу (см. [мой комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432824/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82#comment470829_432824)).